# Which "family" do I put in my data using brm function?

Tags: logistic-regression, bayesian, brms

I have a dataset for a logistic regression in brm. My data consists in a column of presence of visual display in frogs and the second column describes their activity period (0=night, 1=day, 2=both). Below, an example of my dataset:

```
visdisp activity
0       0
0       1
1       2
0       2
1       0
1       1
```

Using brm, there is the "family" argument. My model is `visdisp ~ activity` I am not sure what to put in this item. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want a Bernoulli likelihood with logistic link function it's family = bernoulli(link = "logit")